# Stop a script. Just stop it

Tags: scripting

How can I stop a mathematica script?
`Abort[]` does not stop the script, just jump over a number of lines and proceed with next lines of calculations.

Also, killing the kernel seems not good idea. All I want is C++ exit(0); or Java's System.exit(0);.

```
(* 10000 lines of calculations *)
If[a==5,Print["Calculation gives an unacceptable result. I stop execution here"];Abort[]]
(* 10000 lines of calculations *)
```

The script invoked from Mathematica GUI with Shift+Enter.

**Solution as stated by thorimur**

```
Catch[

   (* COMPLETE SCRIPT *)

   (* Lots of calculations *)
   Throw["Calculation must be stopped"];
   Print["Never printed"];
   (* Lots of calculations *)

 ]
```

Comment: How are you invoking the script? As in, can you give a sample command line?

Comment: @PatrickStevens With Shift+Enter from GUI.

Comment: I don't know how behaviour differs in a .wls script in the UI vs on the command line, but if I invoke a script on the command line (`./script.wls`) then the abort works as expected.

Comment: Asked https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240716/getting-different-results-with-abort-run-in-the-documentation-window-vs-a-note which I think may end up being very relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can always abort a running evaluation manually with Command + `.` (or Ctrl + `.`), here are several ways to do this in Mathematica within a given script! It depends on your particular application and setting. The first two are more general than the rest. I'll run through (most of) the possibilities.

1. `Confirm` and `Enclose` are useful for specific control. `Confirm[expr]` checks that `expr` is not a failure (i.e. is not the value `$Failed` or a `Failure`, as I understand it, and exits to the nearest `Enclose`. Otherwise it returns `expr`. (You can also include a tag as an argument and exit to the nearest `Enclose` with that tag; see the docs.) `Enclose` returns a `Failure` if an enclosed `Confirm` gives it one; otherwise it leaves the expression alone. More specific variants are `ConfirmBy[expr, f]` and `ConfirmMatch[expr, patt]`, which work the same way, but in the first case, exits to `Enclose` only if `f[expr]` doesn't give `True`, and in the second, exits to `Enclose` only if `expr` doesn't match the pattern `patt`.
2. `Throw` and `Catch` are similar, but `Throw[x]` always exits to the nearest enclosing `Catch`, which then returns `x`. So, you'd probably want `Throw` to be in a branch of an `If` or something like that. If no `Throw` is encountered, `Catch[expr]` returns `expr` just like `Enclose`. You can also add a tag to `Throw` and `Catch` like with `Confirm`, to control which `Catch` catches which `Throw`.
3. Just for completeness, `Abort[]` and `Interrupt[]` should immediately grind the computation to a halt, just as if you'd pressed Command + `.`. You can also use `Abort[]` like a `Throw`, though, by enclosing it with `CheckAbort[expr, failexpr]`; if `expr` produces an `Abort[]`, `CheckAbort[expr, failexpr]` will evaluate to `failexpr` instead.
4. If you want to end a loop (`Do`, `For`, or `While`) you can use `Break[]` inside it. This just ends the nearest enclosing loop. If you want to simply move on to the next iteration within the loop immediately, but keep the loop going, you can use `Continue[]`.
5. If you want to exit a function definition, you can (well, *sometimes*) use `Return[expr]`. This immediately returns `expr`, but it can be finicky. For example, you might expect `f[x_] := 1 + Return[5]` to return `5` as soon as it encounters it, but instead it returns `1 + Return[5]`—not even `6`. I'd recommend `Throw` and `Catch` for flow control in general instead.
6. If you really want, you can embrace spaghetti and use `Goto[tag]` and `Label[tag]` in, which work almost exactly how you'd expect, with the caveat that `Goto[tag]` and `Label[tag]` have to be at least nested within some common top level compound expression (expression constructed by `;`). So, for example, `{(Goto[tag]; 1), (Label[tag]; Print[3]; 4)}` won't work, but `If[True, If[True, Goto[tag]]]; Print[1]; Label[tag]; Print[2]` will.