# Getting different results with `Abort` run in the documentation window vs a notebook (probably newlines)

Tags: abort

I'm getting different results with respect to `Abort` when performed in a reference documentation notebook vs a new notebook. I am pretty confident it's to do with the newlines I introduced in my new notebook, because it all works fine when I collapse it back onto one line.

```
In[12]:= ClearAll[a]; ClearAll[b];

In[13]:= Print[a];
Abort[];
Print[b]

During evaluation of In[13]:= a

Out[14]= $Aborted

During evaluation of In[13]:= hi
```

But in the documentation window for "tutorial/InterruptsAndAborts", the first evaluable cell:

```
In[3]:= Print[a]; Abort[]; Print[b]

During evaluation of In[3]:= a

Out[3]= $Aborted
```

I've checked `Hold[<that>] // FullForm // CopyToClipboard` and they are not identical, though they do display identically: in my notebook, it's a TagBox monstrosity:

```
\!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Hold", "[", 
RowBox[{"CompoundExpression", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Print", "[", "a", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Abort", "[", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Print", "[", "b", "]"}]}], "]"}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)
```

Whereas in the documentation window it's precisely:

```
Hold[Print[a]; Abort[]; Print[b]]
```

**Question**: why are newlines causing different behaviour with respect to `Abort` here? I am strongly inclined to call this a bug, because the `FullForm` of the expression with newlines displays identically to the `FullForm` of the expression without newlines; it's only when you attempt to copy the held output (e.g. with `CopyToClipboard`) that you discover they're different.

My version:

```
In[12]:= $Version
Out[12]= "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

(This odd behaviour discovered while trying to answer [Stop a script. Just stop it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240714/stop-a-script-just-stop-it) .)

Comment: What's also very interesting is that enclosing the newline version with parentheses changes its behavior to the single line case...

Comment: Each separate line is a separate evaluation, even within the same cell. Check this comment: [assert in notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98882/stop-notebook-evaluation-when-assert-fails/99582#comment268854_98882) and the whole topic. It is about Assert and its issues but boils down to your problem.